# Order by count on multiple associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a post model. A post has_many comments, has_many favorites, and there's a column on the post model called views. I want to order posts by the sum of all 3 of these counts. How can I achieve this with a scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can use find_by_sql to write any sql you want.

Sample code:

```
Post.find_by_sql("select posts.id,posts.title, 
  count(distinct comments.id) as comments_cnt,
  count(distinct favorites.id) as favorites_cnt 
  from posts
  left join comments on  comments.post_id = posts.id
  left join favorites on favorites.post_id = posts.id
  group by posts.id,posts.title
  order by max(posts.views) +  comments_cnt + favorites_cnt DESC")
```

EDIT:

The code above only work for sql_lite or db2, for other dbms :

```
Post.find_by_sql("select posts.id,posts.title, 
  count(distinct comments.id) as comments_cnt,
  count(distinct favorites.id) as favorites_cnt 
  from posts
  left join comments on  comments.post_id = posts.id
  left join favorites on favorites.post_id = posts.id
  group by posts.id,posts.title
  order by max(posts.views) +  count(distinct comments.id) + count(distinct favorites.id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can craft something similar to this:

```
scope :by_views_comments_and_favorites_count, lambda do |order|
  joins(:comments, :favorites)
  .select("
    count(distinct comments.id) comments_count, 
    count(distinct favorites.id) favs_count, 
    views"
  )
  .group('posts.id')
  .order("(favs_count + comments_count + views) #{order}")
end
```

and use the scope like this:

```
Post.by_views_comments_and_favorites_count('desc')
```

If you want to include the subset of posts that may not have comments or favorites, then you would change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` for those two tables, e.g.

```
joins('left join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id')
.joins('left join favorites on favorites.post_id = posts.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this efficiently, (if for example you anticipate having thousands and thousands of posts, with tens of thousands of comments and favourites), then you should create a 'score' column in your post model/table. When ever you register a view, comment or favourite update your score to be (views + comments.count + favourites.count). Then you can create an index on your score column in your chosen database and sorting by that column will be easy and super-speedy.

Answer (score -1):

I can't give you a Ruby answer, but here's a SQL answer:

```
WITH post_counts as (
SELECT post.post_id, post.views,
   COUNT (DISTINCT comment.post_id) as count_comments,
   COUNT (DISTINCT favorite.post_id) as count_favorites
FROM post
   LEFT JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id
   LEFT JOIN favorite ON post.id = favorite.post_id
)
SELECT post_id, views, count_comments, count_favorites
FROM post_counts
ORDER BY views + count_comments + count_favorites DESC;
```

I have no idea how to translate that into a Rails view, though.